# QGIS 2.13.0-Master breaks QGIS Web Client

Tags: qgis-web-client

QGIS 2.13.0-Master adds following line to every Project xml:

```
<WMSRootName type="QString"></WMSRootName>
```

Unfortunately this breaks QGIS Web Client.

Calling QGIS Server with "request=GetProjectSettings" returns no Name for the root layer:

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name/>
<Title>QGIS Mapserver Hello World</Title>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
...
```

To get QGIS Web Client to function properly, we have to add the layer title (i.e. 'QGIS Mapserver Hello World') as WMSRootName or remove WMSRootName completely.

Comment: That is a nice bug report but what exactly is your question?